# React error when installing styled-components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, styled-components

When I install others packages, everything is good, but when I install styled-components I get this error:

`npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-08T23_16_20_252Z-debug-0.log`

(has two questions with this error here in stackoverflow, but both don't both posts didnt solve my problem)

I'm the unique getting this problem when installing styled-components.

I deleted the `node-modules` and the `package-lock.json` and I installed again, but I still get this error. I searched on youtube, google, everything, but I'm still get the same error.

Comment: Try installing an older version of `styled-components`.
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3998#issuecomment-1537371735

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to type

```bash
npm install styled-components@latest
```

in your project terminal.

It will be working!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add styled-components to your dependency folder as follows:

```
{
...,
"dependencies": {
  "styled-components" : "[go to npm website and copy paste latest stable version]",
  }
}
```

then, in the terminal, just type `npm install --save`